# problem with audioRecorderDidFinishRecording: successfully:

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am facing this problem:

I record some audio using the iPhone microphone and upload it to my server. I `record` for say, 40 seconds and call the `upload` function after 41 seconds (timer). Now, the recorded file that is uploaded to the server is not the full file since the function

```
audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:  successfully:
```

is not called before I call the `upload` function. Its called only after the `upload` function is called - no matter when I call the `upload` function - 10 seconds later or 100 seconds later.

In the upload function, I use ASIHTTPRequest and ASIFormDataRequest to upload the file.

Can anyone kindly tell me why this is happening ? Thanks.

Edit #1:
If the  `upload` method is not called, the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording: successfully:` method is never invoked. Pretty strange !

Edit #2:

Relevant methods:

```
(void) upload
{


NSString *urlString = @"<SOME_LINK>";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *fileData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile];
[request setData:fileData withFileName:[fileName copy] andContentType:@"audio/x-caf" forKey:@"userfile"];
[request setPostValue:[appDelegate getRandomXML] forKey:@"random"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];



[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request startSynchronous];

}




- (void) record
{
NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

fileName=[@"recordTest" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@.alac", dateString];

[formatter release];


NSString *documentDirectory=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *mediaPath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName copy]];

NSString *mediaPathFinal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://localhost%@",mediaPath];

recordedTmpFile = [NSURL URLWithString:[mediaPathFinal stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:&error];

recorder.delegate=self;


[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) ([[appDelegate getTimeToRecord] intValue]+1)];

}

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *) recorder  successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
NSLog(@"DONE");
}

- (void) audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioRecorder *) recorder error:(NSError *) error
{
NSLog(@"ERROR");
}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];

[audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];
[audioSession setDelegate:self];

[self record];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:([[appDelegate getTimeToRecord] intValue]+1) target:self selector:@selector(upload) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


}
```

Comment: Why not just upload the file after the finish recording callback method gets called instead of trying to use a timer?

Comment: @Jason : unless the `upload` function is called, the  finish recording callback method never gets called... :-s

Comment: Can you post the whole upload method? Just replace anything that might be private like the upload url or passwords, but otherwise include the entire implementation of upload?

Comment: @Jason : ok, am posting all the relevant methods. Am posting the basic code (i.e. excluding NSLogs and analytics for example .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `-upload` method inside `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` rather than in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: :if the `upload` method is not called, then the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:` is never invoked....

Comment: That is very weird -- I am sure the problem is somewhere else. Incidentally, 

1) why do you call *both* `-[AVAudioRecorder record]` and `-[AVAudioRecorder recordForDuration:]` inside your `record` method?

2) The documentation for both of these methods mentioned in the previous point says that `prepareToRecord` is called implicitly. So you don't need to call it explicitly inside the `record` method.

3) Minor nitpick, but you don't need to set `self` as a delegate twice in the `record` method.

Comment: thanks..actually doing these edits solved the problem...thanks.

Comment: What happens when you call just one of `record` or `recordForDuration:`? I think these multiple calls might be confounding your results somehow.